# Does this set of functions form a vector space over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the set $\mathcal F$ of all functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R^n$, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $a < b$. This is the set of all functions defined on the fixed interval $[a,b]$ that map to a vector in $\mathbb R^n$. If we

- let $\mathbb R$ be the associated field,
- define scalar multiplication ($\cdot$) as $\forall f \in \mathcal F, (\lambda \cdot f)(x) = \lambda \cdot f(x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in [a,b]$, and
- define vector addition ($+$) as $\forall f,g \in \mathcal F, (f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb [a,b]$

then I think that ($\mathcal F,\mathbb R,\cdot,+)$ forms a vector space. Using the definitions above, it seems that the vector space axioms are satisfied, but I may be wrong:

- **Commutativity**: for any $x \in [a,b]$ and $f,g \in \mathcal F$, we have that $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) = g(x) + f(x) = (g + f)(x)$.
- **Associativity**: for any $x \in [a,b]$ and $f,g,h \in \mathcal F$, we have that $(f + g)(x) + h(x) = (f(x) + g(x)) + h(x) = f(x) + (g(x) + h(x)) = f(x) + (g + h)(x)$. Also, for every $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb R$, we have that $(\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2) \cdot f(x) = \lambda_1 \cdot (\lambda_2 \cdot f(x)) = \lambda_1 \cdot (\lambda_2 \cdot f)(x)$.
- **Additive identity**: Let the function $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$ be the additive identity.
- **Additive inverse**: For any $f \in \mathcal F$, let $g(x) = -f(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$ be the additive inverse.
- **Multiplicative identity**: Let $1 \in \mathbb R$ be the multiplicative identity.
- **Distributivity**: For every $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $f,g \in \mathcal F$, we have that $\lambda \cdot (f + g)(x) = \lambda \cdot (f(x) + g(x)) = \lambda f(x) + \lambda g(x) = (\lambda \cdot f)(x) + (\lambda \cdot g)(x)$. We also have that $((\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) \cdot f)(x) = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2) \cdot f(x) = \lambda_1 f(x) + \lambda_2 f(x) = (\lambda_1 \cdot f)(x) + (\lambda_2 \cdot f)(x)$.

Comment: Yes, function space is a vector space.  It gets more interesting when you start talking about *specific* functions which satisfy specific properties.  For example, the set of all *continuous* functions also form a vector space, or given a specific value of $p$ the functions which satisfy $\left(\int_S |f|^p~\text{d}\mu\right)^{1/p}<\infty$ form a vector space, etc... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals and more.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the confirmation. Just had an additional question: according to example 1.24 in *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler, $\mathbb R^{[a,b]}$ (the set of functions that map $[a,b]$ to a real number) is a vector space, and my question was for the more general case where functions map $[a,b]$ to a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of just a real number. Is there a relationship between these two sets of functions? As in, does proving that $\mathbb R^{[a,b]}$ is a vector space imply that the latter is also a vector space?

Comment: I don't know what sort of relationship you are asking for, but the case of mapping to $\Bbb R$ versus $\Bbb R^n$ in general... mapping to $\Bbb R$ is just a special case of mapping to $\Bbb R^n$ where $n=1$, and this is also just a special case of mapping to $V$ where $V$ is a vector space itself.  Yes, they all have many of the same properties.  I can not think of much that varies beyond the obvious observation that the codomains are possibly different.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. More generally, if $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of $K$-vector spaces (in your example $K=\Bbb R,$ $I=[a,b],$ and $V_i=\Bbb R^n$ for every $i\in[a,b]$), the product
$$V:=\prod_{i\in I}V_i$$
can be naturally equipped, in exactly the same manner, with a structure of $K$-vector space. This $V$ is called the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Direct_product_of_modules) of the spaces $V_i.$

Once you know this, you can easily prove that various structures are vector spaces, by simply showing they are sub-vector spaces of such a $V$ (i.e. non-empty subsets closed under the two vector space operations).